# How much data can I read from Smart contract, Is there a limit

Tags: ether, etherscan, ethereumjs

We are aware that reading data is free from the Ethereum Blockchain.
Is there a limit to the amount of data I can read?
If someone runs a never-ending loop on the call, WIll block chain still give unlimited data.

Is there any limit on number of Requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading data, you are only reading it locally from the node you are connected to. The rest of the blockchain is not bothered at all.

Therefore you can only flood your own node - or that of your node service provider (such as Infura or Alchemy). Service providers typically have request limits, so you can only send X request per time Y.

The only limits are therefore whatever limits your node has, or if you use a service provider, whatever limits your service provider imposes.